# How to set same height and width of image using css? Not background image

Tags: html, css

I have to set images with same height and width.I have three images with different height and width. I have to display the same size in the box. Would you help me in this?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/tI5jq2c.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/37w80TG.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/B1MCOtx.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Since background image has the best browser support, why can't you use that?

Comment: Because I am fetching Images from database and I don't know how to display images using CSS with database

Comment: Mr.LGSon, My question is not duplicate. That answer is a displaing background image and I am asking without background.

Comment: You yourself linked this dupe link in a comment to my answer, saying _With the help of background, I already found the answer_. The dupe link also contain answers showing the solution you now accepted, hence it is a duplicate

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that I don't want to use background image because with help of background I found the answer. I want to do without background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `height: 100%;` of class `ul li img` and it will work

```css
ul{
   list-style: none;
}
ul li{
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
ul li img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/tI5jq2c.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/37w80TG.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/B1MCOtx.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

add constant height to your images

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/tI5jq2c.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/37w80TG.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/B1MCOtx.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```